# How to set Session Only login mode in new Firebase (3.0)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

In the old firebase < 3.0, when loging in we were able to specify session type by passing in object { remember: "sessionOnly" } as a parameter

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/");

ref.authWithPassword({
    email: "xxx@xxx.xxx",
    password: "superSecretPassword"
}, function(error, authData) {
    // some code here
}}, { remember: "sessionOnly" });
```

But when using

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("email@xxx.com", "superSecretOne").catch(function(error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
});
```

in new firebase 3.0+, token is save as default to localStorage and I cannot find this functionality anywhere in docs...

Is there a way to set login to "Session Only" mode in Firebase API or do I have to do this myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently sessionOnly authentication is not supported in Firebase 3.0 but the Firebase team is interested in supporting it. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/sessionOnly/firebase-talk/uYMlQny1Jb4/v9wgTQ4pDgAJ

Comment: You can now specify sessionOnly persistence by calling:
`firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)`

For more on this, check https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.2.0 and https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence